# How to calculate where specular highlights converge with an anisotropic shader?

Tags: vector, 3d-meshes, linear-algebra

If you look at a rendering with an anisotropic shader applied you will notice that there are special spots on the 3D surface/mesh where the lights seems to converge, a point where a given vector radiates from or converges to.

For example:

[image]

The specular highlights seem to converge to the corner of the mouth.

Now given a 3D mesh I would like to calculate those points programmatically: what is the formula for that in linear algebra with vectors ?

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: @Zhen here http://whiteflashwhitehit.com/content/2011/02/G_wobble_dance.jpg and look at the mouth in particular, it's evident that there is a singularity there, or just google for "anisotropic shader" in the images

Comment: Why do you want to calculate these points? Knowing this might help providing better answers.

Comment: @nathan-reed the edit is horrible, "singularity" is a term that is being used in many research papers and is much more specific.

Comment: @msell I would like to try an algorithm about 3d geometry, the problem is that everything "starts" from those points.

Comment: @user1154 "Singularity" is actually a very general term; all it means is a place where some mathematical quantity becomes ill-defined, which could be anything.  IMO, "points where specular highlights converge" is a much more specific description of what you're seeking.

Answer (score 3):

Anisotropic lighting requires in addition to normal and texture coordinates also tangent and bitangent vectors for the geometry. These can be calculated from the texture coordinates or created in some other ways. The places where the anisotropic highlights converge are "singularities" of the tangent / bitangent vectors.

As an example see the picture below with anisotropic lighting. The center of the disk is the singularity. The circles with different shades of gray are coming from a 1D texture map, where the angle (V coordinate) is ignored and the radius (U coordinate) determines the sampling location. The tangent vectors follow the circles and bitangent vectors are always pointing outside from the center. These vectors are not uniquely defined in the center thus causing the singularity. Due to this the lighting highlights also converge to the center.

[image: Example image]

Note that for arbitrary surface with only the normal information anisotropic lighting cannot be used. This is because anisotropic lighting by definition behaves differently in one direction compared to another. E.g. in brushed metals it's defined by the brusing direction as illustrated in my example picture. It's possible to generate the tangents and bitangents out of nothing just like texture coordinates, but there is no single correct way to do that.

What comes to your actual question on how to find these spots algorithmically, that depends on what information you have available and how the anisotropy is defined for the model. If you have the tangent and bitangent vectors, you need to find out vertices where they are not uniquely defined. I don't have an algorithm for this, but I think one way would be finding overlapping vertices with the same coordinates but different tangent and bitangent vectors. In the given example the information might not be available, as it looks like it would converge in the mouth. However there is a hole in there, so the geometry of the singularity is actually missing and it's impossible to tell for sure if they would actually converge or just get very close to eachother if the mouth was there.

Comment: your answer is valuable because it offers a condition, you still haven't proposed a real step-by-step process or an algorithm. How do I calculate the tangent space ? Is possible with matrices or quaternions ?

Comment: Sometimes a direction is more valuable than a straight step-by-step solution. You learn more this way.

Comment: @user1154 I doubt anyone has a full step-by-step algorithm for this.  It's not a question I've ever seen before, although an interesting one.  You'll most likely have to work out the details yourself.